# How can I get numbers of case in 2 dimensional list by backTracking

Tags: python

I want to know how can I solve numbers of case in dimensional list

```py
arr = [[0] * 2 for _ in range(2)]
count = 0

def BackTracking(index):
    global count
    if index == 4:
        print(arr)
        return

    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            if arr[i][j] == 0:
                for k in range(3):
                    arr[i][j] = k
                    BackTracking(index+1)
                    arr[i][j] = 0

BackTracking(0)
print(count)
```

My code has many repetitions in the result. How can I get numbers of cases in a 2-dimensional list by backtracking?

Comment: the first line of code does not make sense:  `arr = \[\[0\] \*2 for \_ in range(2)\]`   please correct this.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You never increment `count`.  What are you counting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess, even though you didn't say so, that you are trying to count all the ways the numbers 0, 1, and 2 can be arranged in 4 boxes.  In that case, you do NOT want those two outer loops in your function.  Each call to BackTracking is responsible for filling in exactly one box -- the box specified by "index".  You don't fill the others -- you call `BackTracking(1)` to fill in the second box, which calls `BackTracking(2)` to fill the next box.  That means you have to be able to extract the x and y coordinates from `index`, which fortunately is not hard.

I think this is what you meant to do:

```
arr = [[0] * 2 for _ in range(2)]
count = 0

def BackTracking(index):
    global count
    if index == 4:
        count += 1
        print(arr)
        return

    i = index % 2
    j = index // 2

    for k in range(3):
        arr[i][j] = k
        BackTracking(index+1)
        arr[i][j] = 0

BackTracking(0)
print(count)
```